# Updating Query Matter

Tags: php, mysql

I've defined a user settings page in my website, and there are several forms that appears on that page, I'v written a query for these fields to be updated upon clicking on "submit" button, but some how I end up having this error below;

> User Could Not Be Updated Because:You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near
>   'SHA1(5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8)', ' WHERE id =' at
>   line 1

this is profile settings page codes for the form:

```
    <?php

    $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $uid ")or die(mysql_error());

    $arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

     ?> 

    <form action="?page=profileset&id=<?php echo $arr['id']; ?>" method="post" role="form">

            <label for="first">First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first" id="first" value="<?php echo $arr['first']; ?>" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off">

        </div>

        <div class="from-group">

            <label for="last">Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last" id="last" value="<?php echo $arr['last']; ?>" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off">

        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="from-group">

            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $arr['email']; ?>" placeholder="Email Address" autocomplete="off">

        </div>

        <div class="from-group">

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $arr['password']; ?>" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">

        </div>

        <button id="profile-btn-change" type="submit" class="btn">Submit Changes</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">

    </form>
```

and this is the query which updates this form;

```
                if(isset($_POST['submitted']) == 1){

                $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['first']);
                $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['last']);
                 $password = SHA1($_POST['password']);

                $action = 'Updated';
                $q = "UPDATE users SET first = '".$first."', last = '".$last."', email = '".$_POST['email']."', password = '".$password."' WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'";

                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

                if($r){

                    $message = '<p class="alert alert-success">User Was '.$action.'!</p>';

                        } else {

                    $message = '<p class="alert alert-danger">User Could Not Be '.$action.' Because:'.mysqli_error($dbc);

                        }

            }
```

any consideration is appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot read beyond `WHERE id = $_POST[id]`, do you by any chance know or met [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)? If you don't, you should read about him first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeating the `password =` part in the UPDATE query.

do

```
$password = sha1($_POST[password]);
```

instead of

```
$password = " password = 'SHA1($_POST[password])', ";
```

#### update

make sure you try the update query like

```
$q = "UPDATE users SET first = '".$first."', last = '".$last."', email = '".$_POST['email']."', password = '".$password."' WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'";
```

and try to sanitize the variables while you use them.

Comment: changed it to this $password = SHA1($_POST['password']); but still having this error --> User Could Not Be Updated Because:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: @EscapeCharacter : where did the double quotes come from?

Comment: which double quotes ?

Comment: @EscapeCharacter I am refering to the 1st version of your coment above. Please update the question with the latest code you are trying.

Comment: Well, I get the message "user was updated", but it does not update the database..... same data

Comment: @EscapeCharacter : are you trying like `$_POST[email]` or `$_POST['email']` same case with id also. see the updated query on my post

Comment: changed to the latest query you've mentioned, but still I've got the successful message of "user updated" but the data is not being updated in the table

Comment: @EscapeCharacter : updatet qn with latest code. Also turn on error reporting and update the question with error messages you see.

Comment: question updated with latest code. error reporting is not equal to '0' any more, I've got the success message saying "user was updated", but it's not actually being updated after I refresh the page.

Comment: @EscapeCharacter : just before `$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);` line. `var_dump($q);` and check if the query is proper with update values you need.

Comment: everything is okay expect the id, this is what's shown in the browser ---> string(143) "UPDATE users SET first = 'Alan2', last = 'Quandt', email = 'alan@alan.com', password = '353e8061f2befecb6818ba0c034c632fb0bcae1b' WHERE id = ''" .

Comment: instead of `$_POST['id']` try `$_REQUEST['id']`. as pass it as a query string param in form action. and recheck the query is proper.

Comment: changed to "$_REQUEST['id']", and it worked, I really don't know what was the matter, but I really do appreciate your consideration, thanks bro.

Comment: i forgot you were passing id param as part of the url. So `$_POST` wont contain the value. you have to go for `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET`. no problem.